# How to clear the current call stack on exception before re calling the function again in python3?

Tags: python-3.x, exception, buffer-overflow

I am extremely new to python and error handling. Currently, I have written a program which access a user's email account and gets the contents of the requested email. I use a number based menu to set the filters to select the required email. As is common with any numeric input in python, this gives rise to a potential `ValueError` which needs to be handled. For that, I use an except statement. Inside the except statement, I inform the user of the fact that the field requires a numeric input and then call the function to take the input again, hence resulting in a tail recursion. But, I realized that this is not an ideal solution since eventually, if enough errors are generated, it would lead to a buffer over flow.

So, my question is, is there a better way to achieve the same. As in, is there a way to clear the current call stack and THEN restart the program right from the beginning so as to prevent a buffer over flow?

Thanks for any suggestions.

I have tried to look up several articles on stack over flow and otherwise, but none of them seem to cover the problem I am facing.

Comment: Generally you want your program to follow a consistent procedure, and this is why what you describe really just isn’t done. What you really want to do is have your selection menu put in a `while True` block so that it loops forever. Then, you can call your login functions inside the loop, and any errors like you describe can be handled by early returning the function back into the main loop so it can be called again without pushing up the stack forever.

Comment: Oh. Thanks for your answer. Would it be possible for you to share a code example to describe what you are saying?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a fairly basic example but I think I shows what I was talking about well enough

```py
def getEmail():
    # email logic
    inp = int(input('Input a number >>> '))  # conversion that can throw an error
    return inp


while 1:  # loops forever
    try:
        print(getEmail())
    except ValueError:
        print('Numeric input required')
```

This is quite a good solution since the exception pushes up the stack automatically, meaning that you don't have to call the function inside itself, instead you can let it complete and then call it again.